Training Mask R-CNN on custom data, but the training doesn't stop and produces no output or errors
Here's a brief overview of my process:

I generate a dataset using PyTorch by applying the SAM mask from bounding boxes to my images.
After creating the dataset, I split it into training and testing sets.
I load both sets using torch.utils.data.DataLoader.
I'm using a pre-trained model with 11 classes.

However, I'm encountering an issue during training. The process seems to take an unusually long time, and I'm not seeing any progress or error messages to troubleshoot from.
my dataset

What might be going wrong or how to improve my training process?
